# `ArgumentError: is not a recognized provider` When testing simple file upload for a model using paperclip, rspec and fog as storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip, fog

I am using `Paperclip` for uploading the file and `fog-google` as a storage.
While uploading files from `rails console` and through `API`, everything is working fine. But when I try to test the upload functionality on my model, I am getting `ArgumentError: is not a recognized provider` error.
Below is the test snippet
```ruby

```
context "saving images" do
    it "save image to google cloud storoge" do
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        user.image = File.new("spec/fixtures/some_image.jpg")
        user.save!
        expect(user.reload.image.exists?).to eq(true)
    end
end
```

```

Attaching the JSON secret file generated by Google

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "some-project",
    "private_key_id": "---somekeys----",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n----private key------\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "new-service-account@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "---client-id----------",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/new-service-account%40some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

And Fog configuration file is attached below:

```
google_project: some-project
google_client_email: new-service-account@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
google_json_key_location: ~/Desktop/some-project-8c5573bf9f32.json
```

Comment: Have you passed proper fog credentials and are you sure that your fog credentials are being accessed properly?

Comment: I wonder how your `fog_credentials` look? Can you add that to the question as well? (with keys obfuscated, of course, we're interested in the structure).

Comment: @Sajin, I have tested the credentials properly, and that is why it is working from `rails console` or through my API, I have re-confirmed it by checking my `Google Cloud Storage` bucket. And my uploaded files are visible there. It's only through `RSpec` test, it is complaining for `is not a recognized provider`

Comment: It looks as though the creds passed to it in that context have either a nil provider or empty string. Perhaps the credentials you are using in rails console are coming from dev environment and test environment has no such credentials?

Comment: @geemus, Thanks man, after all it was related to my environment. How silly of me.